# Cannot add data to Azure /dev/sdb1

Tags: linux, azure, storage

I access my Azure VM on linux. Using `df -kh`, I can see my /dev/sdb1 temporary disk
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/zKXmQ.png)

```bash
$ sudo -i blkid
...
/dev/sdb1: PARTUUID="7ec06285-01"
...
```

I want to use it to store data however, despite, googling and reading the Azure documentation, I did not find any way to add data to it.

- cp test /dev/sdb1
  cp: cannot create regular file '/dev/sdb1': Permission denied
- sudo cp test /dev/sdb1
  sudo: unable to resolve host HubertProduction: Temporary failure in name resolution
- mkdir /dev/sdb1/TEST
  mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/dev/sdb1/TEST’: Not a directory

How can I use /dev/sdb1 to store data and access to them?
It is mounted so do I need to format it? if so how?

All the post I found are about the fact this is a temp storage with no backup: I understand it and this is not the issue here.

Comment: Generally, are you aware of how to mount disks? Also, that VM is it running Linux or is it running in Linux? That's details that are really unclear. Please take the [tour] and read [ask] as a new user here. I believe that general system use (this is not about programming) is better off at e.g. superuser.com. Make sure to first study the site guidelines there, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created one Linux Ubuntu VM and created one directory and mounted it on sdb1 temporary disk like below

Without sudo :-

```bash
mkdir /data2
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/data2’: Permission denied
```

With sudo, It worked:-

```bash
sudo mkdir /data2
```

Mounted dir data2 on sdb1

```bash
sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /data2
cd /data2
```

Accessed data2

```bash
siliconuser@siliconvm:/data2$ lsblk
```

[image]

Now you can directly create files in /data2 and those files will be stored in the temporary disk sdb1

Refer below :-

[image]

You do not need to format the disk as it is already mounted on Azure Linux VM. But you can change its mounted directory from mnt to dir.

You can create the file by moving to /mnt directory where temporary disk sdb1 is mounted by default after vm creation without a need to mount sdb1 to another directory :-
Refer below :-

[image]

[image]

[image]

Its also showing DATALOSS_WARNING readme file which states that the files created under this directory will be deleted as this is a temporary disk.

Reference :-
https://amalgjose.com/2021/09/01/how-to-add-a-new-disk-to-a-linux-server-without-downtime-or-reboot/

Comment: Thansk, this was very helpful and clear. However I encountered this error when running sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /data2:  "mount: /data2: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdb1, missing codepage or helper program, or other error." 
I tried reparing the bad block ($ fsck /dev/sdb1) without success. At the end, I sorted it out by formating the partition first ($ sudo mkfs.ext4 /dev/sdb1) and finally I was able to mount /data2